# Locate function location in a package

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to locate a function (or an entity, in general) inside a package's source code without installing it/consuming it?

For example, is there a way to map the function `isEqual` to this file path: `eqDeep.js` in [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking exactly. What is the thing you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, no. Since functions are defined dynamically, there's no way to know where a function comes from without executing the module to get the exports. Consider the following module:

```
module.exports = {
  myfunction: process.env.PWD.length > 33 ? ()=>'deep' : require('./myotherfunction') 
}
```

Depending on your working directory when you import the module, the function might come from a different file!

Note: don't do this, your program's behaviour will be extremely confusing